# How can I make an if statement that asks, if the number equals to 8 to the power of n (8^n)?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to do an `if` statement that looks something like this:

*(`n` is a natural number)*

```js
if (number == 8^n) {
  // Code...
}
```

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: Normally, this question would be downvoted because it tells that you didn't try to help yourself first by doing your own research. Just try to search for the term 'JavaScript Math.pow' on Google. About the `if` statement, you already got it right

Comment: @orimdominic but then I have to give a value n with it. My question is if I can check if the number Im checking, generally is 1,8,64,512,4096,....

Comment: @BurakErtan I'm so sorry to see your question downvoted. Your question states what you are trying to do. Can you modify your question to add more clarity and include 'what you are trying to achieve' like you did in some comments 
I'll be glad to answer when you're done
God luck

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.pow(x, y);

Example:

```
function check(number,n){
  let r = Math.pow(8, n);
  if (number==r)
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: but then I have to give a value n with it. My question is if I can check if the number is 8 to the power of any n (1,8,64,512,4096,....)

Comment: @BurakErtan So only add for loop in the function that check for every n

Answer (score 1):

```
var n=parseInt(prompt("Enter N:"));
var _number =parseInt(prompt("Enter Number:"));
if(!isNaN(n) && !isNaN(_number))
{
  if(_number == Math.pow(8, n))
    console.log("Equal");
  else
    console.log("Not Equal");
}else
   console.log("Invalid N / Number");
```

Or

```
var n=parseInt(prompt("Enter N:"));
var _number =parseInt(prompt("Enter Number:"));
if(isNaN(n))
   console.log("Invalid N");
else if(isNaN(_number))
   console.log("Invalid N");
else
{
  if(_number == Math.pow(8, n))
    console.log("Equal");
  else
    console.log("Not Equal");
}
```